# each key must be a number of string; got function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cucumberjs

I have this scenario in Cucumber:

```
Scenario Outline: Protractor and Cucumber Test InValid

    Given I have already......
    When I fill the <number>
    ....


    Examples:
| number|...
| 3 |...
|4  |...
```

And I have this stepdefinition in a .js file:

```
 When('I fill the {int}',{timeout: 90 * 1000},  function(callback, number) {

        element(by.css("*[id='field_identificador']")).click();
        element(by.css("*[id='field_identificador']")).sendKeys(number).then(callback);

    });
```

I am getting this error: **each key must be a number of string; got function**

When I execute the test by putting a value by myself without scenario outline, for example: .sendKeys('4') it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your arguments in the wrong order. `callback` is always the last element in the arguments list.

fix:

```
When('I fill the {int}',{timeout: 90 * 1000},  function(number, callback) {

        element(by.css("*[id='field_identificador']")).click();
        element(by.css("*[id='field_identificador']")).sendKeys(number).then(callback);

    });
```